# Explode error with php <?>

Tags: php, explode

Hello i have this string which is an serial of code/references for things:

```
<?PHP

$list="1010<1>;1020<?>;3010<?>";  the list of items code
$id="5060<?>"; //will add this 

$list_unique=explode(";", $list); 


print_r($list_unique);

?>
```

Now the output is: Array ( [0] => 1010<1> [1] => 1020 [2] => 3010 )
Why? it forgots the  part why? it should be

> Array ( [0] => 1010<1> [1] => 1020<*?> [2] => 3010<*?> )

Comment: Dont know ... i think he might interpret the ?> as a closing php tag. But not sure tbh.

Comment: If you put this in file.php and run `php -f file.php` you will see what you wanted.

Comment: you guys are right. But i cannot even write the <*?> part here because stackoverflow strips it... But indeed its an HTML issue. The Full output is in correct format

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're probably viewing the output as rendered HTML. View source and you'll see it isn't missing.

Alternatively, escape your output when you inspect it.

```
echo htmlspecialchars( print_r($list_unique, 1 ) );
```

Answer (score 4):

Always `var_dump($yourvar);` instead of `print_r($yourvar);` if you are unsure of your results.

`var_dump($list_unique);` gave me this

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(7) "1010<1>"
  [1]=>
  string(7) "1020<?>"
  [2]=>
  string(7) "3010<?>"
}
```